# .htaccess mod_rewrite skips capture group when group is empty

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using .htaccess to rewrite URLs with two groupings.

**My .htaccess:**

```
RewriteRule ^tips/([0-9]*)/?([0-9]*)?/?(.+)?$ /tips.php?item=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

It works correctly when there are two numbers are in the URL, but when one is empty, it skips the capture group entirely.

```
example.com/tips/1/2/abc -> /tips.php?item=1&id=2 (EXPECTED)

example.com/tips//2/abc  -> /tips.php?item=2&id=  (UNEXPECTED)
                            /tips.php?item=&id=2  (WHAT WAS EXPECTED)
```

I've put this into a few regex/htaccess testers but they all seem to say it should be working as I expected.

(This of course is an unusual URL, but I want to pass it to PHP so I can handle the error in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rewrite rule with a `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+tips/(\d*)/(\d*)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ tips.php?item=%1&id=%2 [L,QSA]
```

`mod_rewrite` engine converts multiple `//` into a single `/` in `RewriteRule` pattern therefore we need to use `THE_REQUEST` here that matches against original request received in Apache.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^tips/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ tips.php?item=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This will look for non existing files/directories and rewrite them to php file with parameters, like @anubhava sir mentioned multiple `/`slashes will be converted to single `/` by rewrite rule so this should work for both of your mentioned cases.